# Duplex printing feature not recognized by CentOS 6.9?

Tags: cups, socket, printer

I'm having trouble correctly setting up an Epson SX535WD network printer to print two-sided (along the long edge) pages.

I've downloaded two `*.rpm` files from Epson's website but I think the `*.ppd` files are not getting recognized by the OS because when I try to print any pdf document via *evince*...

1. the print out doesn't come out well-centered in A4 format pages but seem to have been scaled down and nailed to the upper left corner of the sheet;
2. duplex feature (or `sides=two-sided-long-edge`) is missing but I know that this model supports it. Why is it not there?

I tried to *manually* decompress the corresponding `.ppd` file under `/opt/epson-inkjet-printer-201106w/ppds/Epson/Epson-Stylus_SX535WD_Series-epson-driver.ppd.gz`, place it in two possible locations for the OS to find them (`/usr/share/ppd` and `/usr/share/cups/model`), then restarted the cups service (`sudo service cups restart`).

So far no luck in getting the Duplex feature recognized by *evince*'s printer GUI. What am I missing out?

```
$ ls -hl /usr/share/ppd
total 376K
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 4.0K Dec 12 13:48 Epson
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   38 Dec 10 15:39 epson-inkjet-printer-201106w -> /opt/epson-inkjet-printer-201106w/ppds
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   36 Dec 17 22:07 epson-inkjet-printer-escpr -> /opt/epson-inkjet-printer-escpr/ppds
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 350K Jan  9 23:30 Epson-Stylus_SX535WD_Series-epson-driver.ppd
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  20K Mar 31  2017 HP
$

$ ls -hl /usr/share/cups/model/
total 380K
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 350K Jan  9 23:30 Epson-Stylus_SX535WD_Series-epson-driver.ppd
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   28 Mar 31  2017 foomatic-db-ppds -> ../../foomatic/db/source/PPD
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  10K May 15  2017 pxlcolor.ppd
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 9.8K May 15  2017 pxlmono.ppd
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1.4K May 30  2017 textonly.ppd
$
```

Answer (score 2):

The `.ppd` file is automatically loaded via CUPS web interface. Go to your web browser, open `localhost:631`, choose Administration > Printers > *name of your printer* (for me, that would be `localhost:631/printers/epson`). Choose to "Modify" your printer from the drop-down menu. If prompted, type `root` as username and its corresponding password. Follow the guided procedure and pick either a driver from the ones listed or browse for a PPD saved somewhere in your local system.[image] Once you finalize your modifications you may "Set your default options", yet again from the`localhost:631/printers/epson`.
[image]
You can now specify "No reduction" of the document to print and turn on "Duplex printing" by the long edge of the page.